# Compare only files within the same source folder vs. Compare only files within the same source and sub folder

Tags: deduplication

Isn't 2 and 4 identical? Can you please distinguish them?  Subfolders must be within the source folder. Then "within the same source folder" in 2 must include all subfolders.

1. Compare files from all source folders
2. Compare only files within the same source folder
3. Compare only files between different source folders
4. Compare only files within the same source and sub folder

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aiUc.jpg. ***Can you please make this picture appear? I don't have enough rep. Thanks.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess using option 4 means the files must be in the same source folder AND sub folder. using option 2 the files must in the same source folder but can be inside different sub folders.